# Laravel auth() is not working in ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I put my route under auth middleware group and also passed the csrf token in the header and but after all this, I am still getting **'Unauthenticated'** message. But this error message only comes in the live server and firefox browser and it's working nicely in my local server and chrome browser.

Here is my route

```
Route::middleware(['middleware' => 'auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/test', [TestController::class, 'getTest']);
})
```

My ajax call

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
          Accept: "application/json",
           "Content-Type": "application/json"
     }
 });

$.ajax({
   url: "{{ url('/test') }}",
   type: "get",
   data: {
      id: {{ auth()->user()->id }}
   },
   success: function(response) {
      var data = JSON.parse(response)
   }
})
```

And my controller

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Does it work locally using Firefox? What's the difference between the requests? Does your application's log contain any information about this?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried to add the token in the header and check the Kernal.php to make sure there is Auth middleware is placed. Yes, it works locally. No difference between local requests and live requests. No Log contains anything about this request